# How to create an empty circle in ReactJS recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is it possible to create an empty circle (only with border) in ReactJS [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/) scatter chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with:

```
<Scatter
name="name" data={dataWithOnlyOnePoint}
fill="transparent" stroke="cyan"
>
</Scatter>
```